# Published App.. Unable to figure out how to locate it

Tags: android, publishing, locate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Publishing an App on Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809682/publishing-an-app-on-google-play)

I published my first app. I have no idea how to find it. This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
 package="com.wecarepeople.hopeapp" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">   
  <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name=".DefaultActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
```

I am *assuming* by the looks of everything that:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wecarepeople.hopeapp

Should take to me the app... but it's not. Which means maybe I screwed up. Which is possible, I sometimes screw up often... *BUT* I have like 400 people expecting to see this app live next week at an event we are having.. and that means I can't count on myself to figure it out.

*help?*

Comment: Thanks. I will try the waiting a few hours. (I've waited a total of like 30 minutes) Screw ups  and lack of patience are two of my flaws. I blame the internet, and it's whole "instant gratification" way of spoiling me. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You probably did not screw up. Publishing is not instant, although it gives you the impression it is. I have had apps appear at their url after a couple of hours waiting.

If it has the status "Published" in your Google Play Console, just check back in a couple of hours and it will be there.

Comment: Just a little bit of extra info: I've seen it take up to 29 hours to be added to the Play Store.

Answer (score 2):

How long ago did you publish it? In my experience, it can take a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the app isn't published. Check the developer panel and make sure that it has a green check mark and says "Published"

Also, it usually takes a few hours for a published app or changes to show up on the store. If it is published and isn't showing up, then all you have to do is wait.